# Connect to a MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a form where users can enter information and it will enter into the database on the website:

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Only problem. It will work for me great because I can manually enter the feilds of my database information

```
($servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";)
```

But I am planning on releasing this form out to the public and I want them to not have to edit every single .php file (theres going to be about five php files)

How can I have it so they can "set it up" the first time they install these forms on their site.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by having all the database settings inside a separate file, e.g. dbsettings.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";
?>
```

In the file that you would normally do the database connection, instead of just connecting your database using:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

You would [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the database settings file first.

```
   <?php

    include 'dbsettings.php';
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
    VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

This is how you do it in PHP. You will see similar setup used in Wordpress, and all other PHP frameworks like Laravel, FuelPHP, CodeIgniter etc (it might be a good idea to use these for bigger projects).